# (How) can I add a second domain to a website to improve SEO?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, web, seo

So I'm making a website for a restaurant in a village in France. The restaurant is called Le Cantou, so I've registered www.lecantou.net. I want to make sure it is easy to find with Google. Now people obviously are not going to type in the name of the restaurant in Google, they will write "restaurant a saint cirq lapopie", because that's the name of the village. So I've also registered http://restaurant-a-saint-cirq-lapopie.com in the hopes that that will make it clear to the visitor that this is the restaurant they want.

Now my question is, I have one website with two domains: is there a way to handle the two domains so I get maximum SEO? I think duplicating the website is a bad idea. But setting a redirect from the long domain name to the original domain name also doesn't work, because then the long domain name will never show up in Google results, isn't that right?

What do you guys recommend?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to give up on "the longer domain". Since Google's [EMD Update](http://searchengineland.com/library/google/emd-update), having domain witch includes the same keywords like popular search queries, won't help you rank better.

You should work more on the content, interaction with your visitors and getting the links from the local websites. That will help you improve the rankings.

Answer (score 0):

Adding multiple domains to a website is a tricky procedure as Google(or other search engine) can easily find out the multiple domains or duplicate links with the help of sophisticated algorithms. Secondary domains pointing to the primary ones can be created through 301Redirects which is a safe technique. All the online visitors can be directed to the secondary domains easily.

Comment: Isn't it true that if I create a 301 redirect that then Google will never put the first domain in their search results, but will only use the domain that is redirected to?

Comment: It's true. But if it's not indexed, then it doesn't have a point anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As the other guys have said - you need to shift your focus from old-school SEO thinking.

Instead try and create an awesome website on your main domain, awesome content, etc.

Don't go for a superlong keyword heavy domain. It probably won't work.